# Como alterar color do Link em HTML?

Tags: css, html5

Saudação para todos,

estou estudando HTML com CSS e ainda estou em processo de aprendizado, eu criei um chaveado, ou seja, quando a pagina está acima de 992px de largura ele mostra o menu, quando está menos de 992px ele esconde um menu e aparece um icone e quando ele quiser clicar para aparece o menu.

O problema é que não consigo inserir a cor na fonte do link dentro do max-width, é só isso.

meu projeto completo está **[aqui](https://github.com/wladimirbandeira/HTML-project/tree/master/Condonager)**

Essa é a parte do código que estou com dificuldade.

```
    <nav class="navegacao">
          <img src="images/logo.png" width="320" height="100">
        <div class="navegacao_menu">
            <button class="botao-chaveador js-botao-chaveado"></button> 

            <ul class="menu  js-menu">
                <li class="menu_item">
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu_item">
                    <a href="#servicos">Nossos Serviços</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu_item">
                    <a href="#">Imóveis</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu_item">
                    <a href="#">Nos conheça</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu_item">
                    <a href="#">Contatos</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>  
    </nav>
```

Esse é a parte do código que envolve o problema;

```
.menu{
    margin: 0;

    font-size: 1.8rem;

    list-style: none;
}


@media(max-width: 991px){

    .menu{
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 200px;
        display: none;
        background-color: #bfbfbf; 
        border-right: 1px solid #eee;
    }

    .menu a{
        color: black;
    }


    .menu--exibindo{
        display: block;
    }

    .menu_item{
        display: block;
        line-height: 3;
    }
}


@media(min-width: 992px ){
    .menu_item{
        display: inline-block;
        padding-right: 20px;
        line-height: 8.5;
    }
}
```

Eu tentei dessa forma, mas não deu certo;

```
.menu a{
        color: black;
    }
```

Eu poderia colocar esse código fora do max-width e do min-width, e funcionaria, porém se eu fizer isso vai ficar com cores fixas tanto com resolução baixa como em resolução alta e esse não é o objetivo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você está utilizando bootstrap no seu código, o estilo dele vai prevalecer, podemos arrumar isso de duas formas:
1-) Da forma que foi dita na primeira resposta

2-) Dando importância ao seu código:

```
 .menu{
 margin: 0;

 font-size: 1.8rem;

 list-style: none;
 }


@media(max-width: 991px){

.menu{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 200px;
    display: none;
    background-color: #bfbfbf; 
    border-right: 1px solid #eee;
}

.menu a{
    color: black !Important; /* Colocamos !Important na frente para que o código tenha preferencia */
}


.menu--exibindo{
    display: block;
}

.menu_item{
    display: block;
    line-height: 3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Isso esta acorrendo por causa que você esta usando `bootstrap.min` ele tem um elemento *anchor (a)* , com uma cor pre-definida se você quiser mudar a cor vai ter que sobrepor as regras dele ou mudar no próprio `bootstrap.min` ontem tem a cor do link.

`a{color:#337ab7;text-decoration:none}`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]